# Here is a question about infinitesimal things that I don't know how to prove

Tags: limits, infinity

Calculate the following limit

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(\sin1)^2+(\sin2)^2+...+(\sin n)^2}$$

Comment: The limit makes not much sense because it does not depend on $x$, resp. it's just the term right of $\lim$.

Comment: sorry，the x should change into  n

Answer (score 2):

We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3015517/695196) that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2(k) = \frac{n}{2}  + \frac{1-\csc(1) \sin(2n+1)}{4}
$$
And since $|\sin(x)| \le 1$ we can say that
$$
\frac{n}{2} + C_1
<\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2(k) < \frac{n}{2} + C_2
$$
where $C_{1}, C_2$ are some constants. Can you conclude from here?